# Beginner logic development

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer in C# who just got started. I have a task at hand where a program needs to read a string and perform some string manipulation. The UI provides a `TextBox` and all the options below as `CheckBox`es. User can select any or all.

1. Remove any spaces.
2. Remove any special chars like ',' etc.
3. Remove any numbers.
4. Convert to camelCase.

There can be more options as part of the string cleanup. I have wrttten the string processing in a method, that has a chasm of if ... else ifs ...

I am sure there is a way around.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks for all the solutions, but I think my point did was not put across correctly.
The string processing will be done in a particular order depending on the checkbox value.
User might select just one or every option provided. In case there is more than one selected, it should be like

```
if(RemoveSpaces.checked)
{
    RemoveSpaces(string inputString);
    // After removing spaces do the other operations
}
else if (RemoveSpecialChars.checked)
{
    RemoveSpecialChars(string inputString);
    // Do other processing
}
```

Comment: What help do you need - Better coding structure? What do you have at the moment (show us the code)?

Comment: You could execute your code on the checkbox events. So when they get checked it executes the code rather than if elseing all of it.

Comment: post that string processing code.

Comment: Are you asking if the "if, else" statements could be better constructed or are you asking for better ways to write the options 1 > 4?

Comment: As there's no question, here's my contribution: do the camel case before removing the spaces ;-)

Comment: Get a book first, dont try to run if you dont know how to walk

Comment: remember to leave a copy of the original input string.

Answer (score 3):

For easy String manipulation, use String.replace

See  [String.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

This code example might also help:

```
string start = "a b 3 4 5.7";
string noSpace = start.Replace(" ", "");
string noDot = noSpace.Replace(".", "");
string noNumbers = Regex.Replace(noDot, "[0-9]", "");

Console.WriteLine(start);
Console.WriteLine(noSpace);
Console.WriteLine(noDot);
Console.WriteLine(noNumbers);
```

The output will then be as follows

```
"a b 3 4 5.7"  // start
"ab345.7"  // noSpace
"ab3457" // noDot
"ab" // noNumbers
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make some class and 4 functions inside. for example:

```
public static class StringOperations
{
    public static string RemoveSpaces(string sourceString)
    {
        string convertedString = "";
        //some operations
        return convertedString;
    }

    public static string RemoveCharacters(string sourceString, params char[] charactersToRemove)
    {
        string convertedString = "";
        //some operations
        return convertedString;
    }

    public static string RemoveAnyNumbers(string sourceString)
    {
        string convertedString = "";
        //some operations
        return convertedString;
    }

    public static string ConvertToCamelCase(string sourceString)
    {
        string convertedString = "";
        //some operations
        return convertedString;
    }
}
```

In Your UI you just call one of functions...